# Why does a long link in a <td /> expand width to 100%?

Tags: html, html-table

Here is my table:

```
<table width="600px">
    <tr>
        <td width="75%">
            <p style="line-height: 140%; font-size: 15px; padding: 0 0 28px 0; margin: 0;">
                <a href="http://#SERVER_NAME#/auth/index.php?confirm_registration=yes&confirm_user_id=#USER_ID#&confirm_code=#CONFIRM_CODE#" style="color: #ca0049 !important;">
                     http://#SERVER_NAME#/auth/index.php?confirm_registration=yes&confirm_user_id=#USER_ID#&confirm_code=#CONFIRM_CODE#
                </a>
            </p>
        </td>
        <td width="25%"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What do you expect? You have very long link, this is default behaviour of the table - it will extend and not respect the width.

Comment: You are missing a </tr> element.

Answer (score 0):

The “text” of the link has no character that would allow line breaks in all browsers, so browsers may feel forced to keep it on one line and extend the width of the cell. Modern browsers generally treat some of the special characters as allowing a line break after it, but they do this inconsistently and in an undocumented manner.

The most natural solution is to use a sensible link text, consisting of natural language words, such as “Confirm registration”.

If you really must have a URL as link “text” (for teaching purposes?), then it is best to wrap the URL in quotation marks (or otherwise delimited as recommended in [STD 66](http://tools.ietf.org/html/std66) appendix C) and insert line break opportunities (either zero width spaces or `<wbr>` tags, see http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/nobr.html) at positions where they are acceptable by STD 66, e.g.

```
http://#SERVER_NAME#/<wbr>auth/<wbr>index.php?<wbr>confirm_registration=yes&<wbr>confirm_user_id=#USER_ID#&<wbr>confirm_code=#CONFIRM_CODE#
```